# Making a rows value to be anothers text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have a table with 2 rows, the first has an input for quantity and the following has to output that same value. Since I'm using jQuery this is my code:

```
var i, quant;

for (i = 0; i < $(".qnt").length; i++){
    $(".qnt:eq(" + i + ")").keyup(function(){
        quant = $(this).val();  
        console.log($(this));
        console.log(i);
        console.log($(".cst:eq(" + i + ")"));
        $(".cst:eq(" + i + ")").text(quant);
    });
}
```

And the sample for the rows is :

```
<tr>
     <td><input class="qnt"/></td><td class="cst"></td>
</tr>
```

The jsfiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/qrhJ4/

Question : why is the .cst selector not working and how do I make it work?

Comment: I think this is pretty simple.  can you please put up a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over-complicating things, try something like:

```
$('.qnt').keyup(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.cst').text(this.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aasqW/

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro if you look in your logs, `i` will always be the same because of JavaScript closure. When the keyup event triggers, the loop has already finished. Anyway, it’s better to use the target element as base and then traverse from there in the event handler.